# How to find interface in assemblies? For plugin system

Tags: c#, reflection, mono

I am trying to create a plugin system but I get "Object reference not set to object" Error.

I have loaded each dll as a assembly then used Assembly.GetTypes(). I loop through my types to find my IPlugin interface. I then use Activator.CreateInstance() to create a new IPlugin for a reference and add it to my Plugins list.

```
           foreach(string dll in dllFiles) {
                AssemblyName an = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(dll);
                Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(an);

                Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();

                foreach(Type type in types) {
                    if(type.GetInterface(PluginType.FullName) != null) {
                        IPlugin plugin = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IPlugin;
                        Plugins.Add(plugin);
                        Console.WriteLine("Added a plugin!");
                    }
                }
            }
```

I expect to be able to loop through my Plugins list and call the method "Do()" in each but I get a object reference not set to object.

Comment: you probably want in the `if` statement `type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(IPlugin))` and then create an instance of it and cast to IPlugin?

Comment: @Minijack interface implementation and superclasses are two different things. It won't work.

Comment: The way I interpreted the question is "these Assemblies contain plugin types of Type `IPlugin`. How do I find them and add them to the `Plugins` `List`?" Is op trying to find the Interface `IPlugin` in the Assembly or types that implement `IPlugin`?

Comment: What line are you getting the error at?

Comment: I get the error when trying to use the IPlugin type from the list with `Console.WriteLine(Plugins[0].Name);` I am trying to replicate : [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1052356/Creating-a-Simple-Plugin-System-with-NET).